# Using OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory to output UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to return an Excel-friendly csv file with non-Latin characters from an implementation of `TextOutputFormatter`. The following code shows the essentials bits:

```cs
public class CsvOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    private readonly UTF8Encoding _encoding;

    public CsvOutputFormatter()
    {
        _encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(_encoding);
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {

        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=test.csv");

        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        var preamble = _encoding.GetPreamble();
        response.Body.Write(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);
        // this works
        //using (var writer = new StreamWriter(response.Body, _encoding))
        // this doesn't work
        using (var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, _encoding))
        {
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = true;
            csv.WriteRecords((IEnumerable<object>)context.Object);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

My main questions is why the BOM not output when using `OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory`?

Side questions:

1. What's the added value of using `OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory` instead of a regular `StreamWriter`, which works just fine in this case?
2. Is there a way to avoid explicitly writing the BOM, e.g. have a writer calling `Encoding.GetPreamble()` automatically?
3. I'm aware that UTF-8 with BOM is non-standard, I wonder though if there is a way to avoid it in this case?

Answer (score 4):

> What's the added value of using OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory instead of a regular StreamWriter, which works just fine in this case?

Actually, you could write to `HttpResponse.Body` directly if you like. The point is, as the document describes, don't use `WriterFactory` when you want to write binary data.

The ASP.NET Core uses the **`HttpResponseStreamWriter`** to write stream behind the scenes (See [MemoryPoolHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/MemoryPoolHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory.cs#L73))
. This implementation exposes several methods which are quite similar to [**`StreamWriter`**](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/9773db1e7b1acb3ec75c9cc0e36bd62dcbacd6d5/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L17). But the `HttpResponseStreamWriter` uses **`ArrayPool<>`** behind the hood. According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netcore-2.1), it should **improve performance** when arrays are created and destroyed frequently.

> My main questions is why the BOM not output when using OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory?

That's because the `HttpResponseStreamWriter` [doesn't write `BOM`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/92cae6faab9cd414eccf77eab687c32c7a6a0f1b/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/HttpResponseStreamWriter.cs#L16) at all :

```
/// <summary<
/// Writes to the  using the supplied .
/// It does not write the BOM and also does not close the stream.
/// </summary<
public class HttpResponseStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    private const int MinBufferSize = 128;
    internal const int DefaultBufferSize = 16 * 1024;
    ...
}
```

> Is there a way to avoid explicitly writing the BOM, e.g. have a writer calling Encoding.GetPreamble() automatically?

If you're using the built-in `OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory`, I believe the answer is **YES**. You need to write the BOM header by your self if you wish.

---

Lastly, you should not **write headers within the `WriteResponseBodyAsync()` method**. That's a duty of `WriteResponseHeaders(ctx)`. It's better to move this codes to **`WriteResponseHeaders(OutputFormatterWriteContext ctx )`**:

```
    public override void WriteResponseHeaders(OutputFormatterWriteContext ctx )
    {
        var response = ctx.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=test.csv");
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var preamble = _encoding.GetPreamble();
        response.Body.Write(preamble, 0, preamble.Length);
        using (var writer = context.WriterFactory(response.Body, _encoding))
        {
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields =  true;
            csv.WriteRecords((IEnumerable<object>)context.Object);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: _That's because the HttpResponseStreamWriter doesn't write BOM at all :_

But I write BOM manually directly to `response.Body` before even getting to WriterFactory. What happens to that?

Comment: @LeonV In that case, the `BOM` will be written to the stream. But note that is not done by `HttpResponseStreamWriter` automatically, but by the `Body` stream (`Stream.Write()`). Actually, if you look at the final code I post above, it works in the way as you describe.

Comment: _If you're using the built-in OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory, I believe the answer is YES. You need to write the BOM header by your self if you wish._ 
Well, this is exactly what I do - write BOM by myself. The question is if there is a way to avoid it.

Comment: @LeonV No way if you using the built-in `OutputFormatterWriteContext.WriterFactory` unless you do it manually. The [StreamWriter will do that](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/9773db1e7b1acb3ec75c9cc0e36bd62dcbacd6d5/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/StreamWriter.cs#L267).

Comment: Your final code is very similar to mine, aside from writing headers in a separate method and does NOT produce BOM. That was the essence of my question.

Comment: @LeonV Do you copy&paste my code? I dump the hex and do see a `EF BB BF` BOM header.

Comment: _Lastly, you should not write headers within the WriteResponseBodyAsync() method. That's a duty of  WriteResponseHeaders(ctx). It's better to move this codes to_ thanks for that, do you happen to know the reason for that separation (other than slightly better maintainability)? Headers don't need encoding, I get it, but is there anything else to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193758/discussion-between-itminus-and-leon-v).